# Add event handlers to each individual list item (jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

how do I add event handlers to each individual item items?

I'm trying to add a onclick event to call theMethod, and at the same time, it will pass it an id to tell the javascript which item id was clicked.

```
function theMethod(id) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#ul_element_selector').delegate('li', 'click', function () {
    theMethod(this.id);
});
```

The code in `theMethod(id)` could also just be placed inside the anonymous function attached to the `click` event for the `li` elements.

The above code assumes that each of the `li`'s have their own unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selector-for-li').click(function() {
    var id = $(this);
    theMethod(id);
    // do stuff
});
```